# alias_method recursion

Tags: ruby, alias

In the following code from [ruby docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-alias_method), why doesn't `orig_exit` end up calling itself in infinite recursion?

```
module Mod
  alias_method :orig_exit, :exit
  def exit(code=0)
    puts "Exiting with code #{code}"
    orig_exit(code)
  end
end
include Mod
exit(99)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> why doesn't orig_exit end up calling itself in infinite recursion?

Because there is no recursion here.

First, `exit` is called, from the last line (`exit(99)`) which in turn calls `orig_exit`, which is a different function. Unless `orig_exit` explicitly calls `exit` (which there is no reason to believe it does) there is no possibility for recursion. When `orig_exit` returns, its return value is returned from `exit` as well.

`alias_method` has renamed the method that *was* named `exit` to `orig_exit`, and then a completely new function named `exit` is defined.